# AngularJS - setting .error CSS class for input form using directive

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a registration form and I want to do live input validation for emails that have already been registered in the database.

I have the directive working so that it fires on every change to the input box, but I'm having trouble getting Angular to set the proper `.error` CSS classes from within the scope.$watch function.

Here is my markup:

```
<form ng-app="mainApp" id="signup_form" name="signup_form" ng-controller="signupController" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate >
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Create New Account</legend>
                        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: signup_form.username.$invalid }">
                            <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"                           
                                ng-model="username" 
                                ng-minlength=3 
                                ng-maxlength=20 required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group" ng-class="{ error: signup_form.email.$invalid}">
                            <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" 
                                ng-model="email"
                                required 
                                uniqueaddress/>         
                            </div>
                        </div>          
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-show="signup_form.$error.required" class="error">Field is required.</li>
                                <li ng-show="signup_form.$error.minlength" class="error">Field must at least 3 characters</li>
                                <li ng-show="signup_form.$error.maxlength" class="error">Field is too long.</li>
                                <li ng-show="signup_form.$error.uniqueaddress" class="error">Email is already in use</li>
                            </ul>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="signup_form.$invalid" class="btn">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Notice the directive attribute 'uniqueaddress' on the second input box. Here is my directive for uniqueaddress:

```
mainApp.directive('uniqueaddress', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) 
        {
            var isEmailValid = false;
            var isEmailValid = scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (email) 
            {
                if(email == 'test')
                    scope.signup_form.$setValidity('uniqueaddress', false);
                else
                    scope.signup_form.$setValidity('uniqueaddress', true);
            });     
        }
    };
});
```

And here is a fiddle of demonstarting the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/k4Cty/10/

Type in any 3 character string and the validation works fine for the username field. For the email field, if you type in the string 'test', the validation fires and the `<li>` item tagged with `ng-show="signup_form.$error.uniqueaddress"` appears however the `.error` class is not being set for `<div class="control-group">` because it does not go red indicating an validation error. It seems to setting the `.error` class for the default `ng-minlength` and `required` directives are firing but not for `uniqueaddress`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/X8mub/4/) takes yours and drops in a pretty standard approach for adding validation using a directive. Main points:

1. `require` the element's `ngModel` controller, where you will wire in your validation.
2. Places a function at the beginning of array of `$parsers` to perform validation when the value is parsed from the DOM.
3. Places a similar function at the beginning of the array of `$formatters` to perform validation when the DOM is updated from the model.

See [this article ("Custom Validation")](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) for more info on how validators work.

You should not try to access the containing form's `$setValidity()` function. That approach is undocumented and has limited reusability. You also want to target the field whose validity you want to check rather than the type of error. Finally `formname.$dirty` is your friend. I think angularJS validators are a bit eager, as it's annoying to have validators giving you error feedback as you are entering a value, and hate seeing errors all over the place when you haven't even filled a form out yet, so anything you can do to make it look less panicky.

Comment: I'm new to Angular and this is good stuff. I had not gotten into $parsers and $formatters yet so I will need to look into these. All the tutorials/blogs I had found used some form of $setValidity so it led me to believe that was the proper way to perform the validation.  Thanks for the quick response!